# Using double integrals correctly

Tags: integration, statistics, multivariable-calculus

I seem to be doing some of the steps wrong, when counting with double integrals. Would someone point out exactly which steps, and what exactly I'm doing wrong?

Example exercise:

The management at a fast food outlet is interested in the joint behavior of the random variables $Y_1$, defined as the total amount of time between a customer's arrival at the store and departure from the service window, and $Y_2$, the time a customer waits in line before reaching the service window. Because $Y_1$ includes the time a customer waits in line, we must have $Y_2 \le Y_1 $. The relative frequency distribution can be modeled by the probability density function:

$$f(y_1, y_2)= \begin{cases}
e^{-y_1}, & 0\le y_1 \le y_2 \le \infty \\ 
0, & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}
$$

With time measured in minutes, find $P(Y_1 \lt2, Y_2 \gt 1 $

I figure this should be solved with a double integral, something like this:

$$\int_1^2 \int_{1}^{Y_1} e^{-y_1}dy$$

My reasoning for setting these limits:

$Y_2$ cannot be less than one, according to the text. Also, $Y_1$ cannot be more than Y_1, since $Y_1$ represents the total time. $Y_1$ cannot be greater than 2, this is also stated. Since $Y_2$ must be greather than 1, this must also be true for $Y_1$.

I start by doing the primitive function of $e^{-y_1}$, with respect to $y_2$:

$$=y_2 e^{-y_1}$$

The partial integral of $y_2$ thus would be:

$$y_1 e^{-y_1}-1 e^{-y_1}=e-e^{-y_1}$$

The primitive function of this, with respect to $y_1$ should be:

$$y_1 e +e^{-y_1}$$

Thus the partial integral with respect to $y_1$ should be

$$2e +e^{-2}-(1\cdot e +e^{-1})=e +e^{-2}-+e^{-1}$$
$$=2.4857\ldots$$

This obviously can't be right, probabilities cannot be greater than 1. Yet I can't figure out where I went wrong. Would someone point out my mistake(s)?

Exercise from "Mathmatical Statistics with Applications,$7^{th}$edition"

Comment: Duly noted. thanks.

Comment: It may help to draw out the region over which you want to integrate, taking into account all the constraints on the $y_i$ values. It looks like you'll need to split the region up into two regions, so that means you'll need to find the sum of **two** double integrals.

Comment: Maybe I should have mentioned this but...according to the proposed solution, this is possible to do with one double integral. The limits in this somewhat different. For Y1 from 2 to Y2 (this seems illogical) and for Y2 from 1 to 2. I've got one solution that yields a correct answer. I just don't know why that works, and my solution does not.

Answer (score 1):

You have $\displaystyle\int_1^2\int_1^{y_1}e^{-y_1}dy_2dy_1=\int_1^2\left[y_2e^{-y_1}\right]_1^{y_1}dy_1=\int_1^2(y_1e^{-y_1}-e^{-y_1})dy=\int_1^2(y_1-1)e^{-y_1}dy_1$.

Using integration by parts, with $u=y_1-1, dv=e^{-y_1}, du=dy_1, v=-e^{-y_1}$, gives

$\displaystyle\left[-(y_1-1)e^{-y_1}-\int-e^{-y_1}dy_1\right]_1^2=\left[-y_1e^{-y_1}+e^{-y_1}-e^{-y_1}\right]_1^2=\left[-y_1e^{-y_1}\right]_1^2=e^{-1}-2e^{-2}$

Comment: This is the correct answer, I don't understand the last part of your solution though (the expression within square brackets in particular).

Comment: To be more precise, I don't understand why the primitive function, with regard to y1, can be written like that.

Comment: I will include more detail in my answer to explain this.

Comment: I figure that $y_1*e^{-y_1}$ does not equal e, and that this was one of my mistakes. Judging from your answer, the primitive function of that expression is hard to get to directly (got something like $-(\frac {y^2}{2}*e^{-y_1})$ when I tried)) .

Comment: You can also use $\int(y-1)e^{-y}dy=\int ye^{-y}dy-\int e^{-y}dy=\int ye^{-y}dy-(-e^{-y})$ and then find the first term using integration by parts with $u=y, dv=e^{-y}dy$